# Regex match last occurrence of substring among the same substrings in the string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

For example we have a string:
asd/asd/asd/asd/1#s_

I need to match this part: /asd/1#s_ or asd/1#s_
How is it possible to do with plain regex?

I've tried negative lookahead like this
But it didn't work

```
\/(?:.(?!\/))?(asd)(\/(([\W\d\w]){1,})|)$
```

it matches this '/asd/asd/asd/asd/asd/asd/1#s_'
from this 'prefix/asd/asd/asd/asd/asd/asd/1#s_'
and I need to match '/asd/1#s_' without all preceding /asd/'s

Match should work with plain regex
Without any helper functions of any programming language
https://regexr.com/
I use this site to check if regex matches or not

here's the possible strings:

```
prefix/asd/asd/asd/1#s
prefix/asd/asd/asd/1s#
prefix/asd/asd/asd/s1#
prefix/asd/asd/asd/s#1
prefix/asd/asd/asd/#1s
prefix/asd/asd/asd/#s1
```

and asd part could be replaced with any word like

```
prefix/a1sd/a1sd/a1sd/1#s
prefix/a1sd/a1sd/a1sd/1s#
...
```

So I need to match last repeating part with everything to the right
And everything to the right could be character, not character, digit, in any order

A more complicated string example:

```
prefix/a1sd/a1sd/a1sd/1s#/ds/dsse/a1sd/22$$@!/123/321/asd
```

this should match that part:

```
/a1sd/22$$@!/123/321/asd
```

Comment: Try `^.*/(\w+)/.*/(\1/\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/w0hy1Q/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird
it doesn't work here :(
https://regexr.com/5av4b

Comment: if pcre is supported https://regexr.com/5avdh In the previous link at the top of the comments, the data is in capture group 2 which has the red color.

Comment: You can see all the matches here with the leading forward slash `^.*(/\w+)/.*\K\1/\S+`  https://regexr.com/5avdh

Comment: @Thefourthbird
wow. \K and \1 did the thing. Didn't know about them before. Thanks! And one more question: if I have this string prefix/ttt/ttt/ttt/1s#/ds/dsse/a1sd/22$$@!/123/321/asd (1 substring instead of many (without repeatings)), I also need the same match. How should I trick \1 to do the match? I've tried something like (\1|\0) but it's wrong in terms of syntax. How to properly do it?

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regexr.com/5avfa

Comment: @Thefourthbird it's the same as in the previous link
Could you copy plain regex here please?

Comment: Ah ok, this pattern `^.*?/(\w+)(?:/.+)?\K/\1/\S+$` https://regex101.com/r/ypDTkq/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird
Ooooh. I meant other thing. To clarify. Input: prefix/a1sd/a1sd/a1sd/1s#/ds/dsse/a1sd/22$$@!/123/321/asd. Output: /a1sd/22$$@!/123/321/asd. Input: prefix/ttt/ttt/ttt/1s#/ds/dsse/a1sd/22$$@!/123/321/asd. Output: the same as in the first case (/a1sd/22$$@!/123/321/asd).

Comment: The pattern is based on the last occurrence of a repeating value like `/a1sd/` Can you tell why the last 2 strings should give the same match?

Comment: @Thefourthbird
because these are the two different cases I need to handle in a single regex
How is it possible?

Comment: You have to specify the rules or logic for getting those 2 matches.

Comment: @Thefourthbird
Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220559/discussion-between-arty-dev-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the match only, you can use `\K` to reset the match buffer right before the parts that you want to match:

```
^.*\K/a\d?sd/\S+
```

The pattern will match

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match any char except a newline until end of the line
- `\K` Forget what is matched until now
- `/a\d?sd/` match a, optional digits and sd between forward slashes
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YF967K/1)